# How can modify the .code segment at runtime?

Tags: assembly, process

I want to write a program that be able to modify the code segment of itself. for example consider this assembly code:

**Orginal code:**

```
i1: mov eax,0
i2: mov eax,0X01
```

**the resulting code that i want be made at runtime by the same code:**

```
i1: mov eax,0
i": // some modifing instructions that when are excuted they change the i2 and/or add or remove some instruction such i3
i2: jmp 0x32
i3: mov ebx,0x67
```

you see the `i2` is changed after executing the instruction(s) `i"`. the `i"` is obliged to modify its forwarding code instructions.

Now my questions are:

1. How to modify the code segment? Or How to address the code segment
   memory area?
2. Are we allow to modify there from the same code segment
   (Not another program that it doesn't have access to there)?
3. how we can solve the problems caused by the changing code segment size?
4. the last problem maybe is the anti-viruses! which they check program's behavior at the runtime and they are sensitive to self-modification.

Thanks my friends.

Comment: 1) write to the memory. 2) Maybe. 3) Difficult, best to leave space originally (insert generous nops). 4) Ack.

Comment: Please add relevant details (OS, CPU) - this shows very little effort.

Comment: Hi. There is a nice deep learning guide, located here: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf . Page 136 with chapter 3.6.7 should help You. I was doing it 5 years ago.

Comment: actually we want to impalement a self-modify program which it modifies its execution code. the CPU or OS Details are not matter because we just need too have modify the code in anyway. for example replicating a specific instruction in the code.

Comment: @KerrekSB How can write to the code memory? and, second question: think about a situation that there are three instructions without any gap there, and we want to add some instructions in the between them. How do this? Shifting the forwarding instructions maybe take long time! and in other hand also adding jump to another place again needs at least one shift. so ...! How you counter with these problems? Thank you.

Comment: If you have no room, it's really tricky, because normal code uses hardcoded addresses and jump targets. You could carve out a larger section of code and move it elsewhere, but parse it to see if it needs fixing up, and fill the hole with a jump to your own code, which does its thing, then executes the moved-out original code, and then jumps back. It all depends on how much work you want to put in and how evil a hack you need to perform. If it's your own code, then you should just recompile it with gaps.

Comment: @AliAdlavaran You're right, shifting forward instructions would take ages, which is why nobody does that. Instead, someone who wants to patch instructions will either use `nop` instructions to serve as the padding, or swap out one instruction for another.

Answer (score 0):

Within the 16 bit realmode and the v86-mode we can simple write to the codesegment:

```
i1: inc bx         ; 43h = opcode of "INC BX"
    mov al,4Bh     ; 4Bh = opcode of "DEC BX"
    mov cs:[i1],al
```

Dirk